# How to do power series expansion by long division?

Tags: power-series

So I have the question

$$\frac{2z+1}{z^2-z+0.5}$$

do I solve the problem of power series by long division like the following?

[what I've done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OoT9.jpg)

I know the power series is infinite but I'm just a little confused on the terminology for the question I'm doing I'm supposed to go to the 4th coefficient but I'm not sure if I'm calculating correctly.

------------------------------------ EDIT

The exact wording of the question is as follows

A causal system is defined by transfer function

$$\frac{2z+1}{z^2-z+0.5}$$

Determine the first four non-zero coefficients of the system’s impulse response, ℎ(), using the power series expansion by long division method.

when I asked the TA who was teaching this section where I could find more info on this he said look at google so I don't know what to do because every example I get from google is talking about doing the inverse of a transfer function.

Comment: OP, can you please clarify whether you want a power series (with positive powers) or a long divison (laurent series)?

Comment: The question says using the power series by long division method, I've never heard of this and what I have accomplished so far is what I've seen on the internet that I suspect is the correct thing to do

Comment: Ah. Then what I have replied with should be what you want. Feel free to ask for clarifications if you don't understand, and accept if it helps!~

Comment: Is there a better name for it that I can look it up by?

Comment: Polynomial long divsion

Comment: Please clarify, Livingstone, whether you are looking for an expansion in positive powers of $z$, or an expansion in negative powers of $z$.

Comment: I don't know the question is as stated above, the work I did was what I did guessing off what I saw on the internet

Comment: OK. Do you know anything relating "impulse response" to "transfer function"?

Comment: @Gareth, I found, "If the transfer function of a system is given by $H(s)$, then the impulse response of a system is given by $h(t)$ where $h(t)$ is the inverse Laplace Transform of $H(s)$." So I think what we're really supposed to find here is the inverse Laplace transform of $(2z+1)/(z^2-z+0.5)$. I think we've all been barking up wrong trees.

Comment: Have you been able to get any clarification, Livingstone? If your TA isn't helpful, is there someone else in charge of the course who can help?

Comment: The TA has been left in charge so no

Comment: How about the head of the department?

Comment: head of department would just tell me to do what I was told

Answer (score 0):

Try to think of it as $$\frac{1}{z^4}\cdot\frac{2z^5+z^4}{z^2-z+0.5}=\frac{1}{z^4}(2z^3+3z^2+2z+\cdots)$$

Comment: Essentially "shifting the powers up" then shifting it back with the z^-4

Comment: But that doesn't give you a power series (in $z$), it gives an expansion in powers of $z^{-1}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's what he did in the linked photo, so I assumed that's what he wants.

Comment: OK. Maybe OP doesn't know what he/she wants. We await clarification from OP.